# Android app does not show ads

Tags: android, admob

Ads don't work..

**In LOG**

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
```

But in app toast "Ad did not load"

**Ads.class**

```
public class Ads extends AppCompatActivity {
PublisherInterstitialAd mPublisherInterstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPublisherInterstitialAd = new PublisherInterstitialAd(this);
    mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

    mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            startActivity(new Intent(Ads.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    });
    requestNewInterstitial();
    showInterstitial();

}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();

    mPublisherInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
public void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
    if (mPublisherInterstitialAd != null && mPublisherInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mPublisherInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(Ads.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
}
```

I tried everything, even created a new ID in AdMob, 
but still does not work.. 
Just tried it on a real device ..

Why?

Answer (score 0):

To know the specific problem implement the `AdFailedToLoad` override method in `AdListner`
and catch the Error code.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR), then you can map what the error code means and understand you problem better.